# how post job using api in all social job platform like indeed, linkdein,facebook,monster

Tags: facebook-graph-api, linkedin-api

I want to integrate my ATS to LinkedIn,indeed,Facebook,monster or dice for post job in one click.how can i post my ATS job to LinkedIn,indeed,Facebook,monster or dice using API?

Comment: _“but all platform required partner permission”_ - and? Looks like you found your answer already then. So what actual _question_ is left to ask now?

Comment: many ATS platform integrated one click job publish to all job platform already so i want to know how they did using API

Comment: Well they probably applied to become such partners first.

Comment: Anyway, you should not be asking this in such a general and broad way for multiple networks at once to begin with here. They all have their own, different APIs, so you will likely have to look at each one of them individually. And that part of actually _looking_ is your responsibility - we are not here to read documentation _for you_.

Comment: i already did but no one response

Comment: Well then you have to wait until you get one. (Or accept the fact that you simply might not get one at all, if your application was not worth considering to them in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

I Got the Solutions.I Have Use ZOHO Recruit or Zip Recruiter Api for posting my jobs to social job platform like indeed, linkdein,facebook,monster